# Need regex library for doing multiple matches in a string for C

Tags: library, c, regex

I am trying to find all the email address links for all the USA senators, I want to do this by Wget and then doing pattern matching with regex. Then I need to print the matches out to the screen.

This is the problem that I need to have this program do

> Part 2: Add to the program a section that loads and parses the
>   downloaded file extracting all of the web addresses. Your program must
>   generate a listing on the screen of the extracted web addresses  when
>   it is run.
>
> - Note that the web list must be perfect - no extra characters - to get full credit.

Is there a way to return all matches of the regex from a string (if so, how would I go about doing it)

Unless I am mistaken, I have only found regex functions that would end up finding a single occurrence of the regex and not all of them.

Here is my current regex that I am going to be using

```
Contact:\s+<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href=(["'])(.*?)\1
```

This regex seems to work perfectly, for what I am looking for.

This is my current setup for code for the program, just don't know how I would go about implementing the Regex

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {


    // initiate all used Variables
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer;
    long size;

    //Wget on Senate webpage
    system("wget -q http://www.senate.gov/general/contact_information/senators_cfm.cfm");


    // Attempt to open file
    file = fopen("senators_cfm.cfm", "r");

    if(file == NULL){

        printf("Was unable to open file \n");
        return 1;        

    }

    //Attempt to read to end of file
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);



    //Determine the number of bytes that were in the file
    size = ftell(file);

    //Attempt to allocate the number of bytes needed
    buffer = (char*) calloc(size, sizeof(char));    
    if(buffer == NULL){

        printf("Unable to allocate memory needed \n");
        return 1;
    }


    //Reset the reader to start of file
    rewind(file);


    //Read whole file into buffer
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);

    //This is where I will be implementing the regex (or at least the call
    //to the function)


    //Close file
    fclose(file);


    //Free all information that we allocated memory for
    free(buffer);

    unlink("senators_cfm.cfm");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the http://www.pcre.org/ library.

Please cut our problem into smaller pieces the next time.

If you current issue is a regex question, then it is unneeded information that you fetch this data with wget.

It is easier to focus on your issues if only the relevant information is in the question.